# Javascript 2023-06-16T12:00:00Z this iso String how can i format it like 10/03/2013 Friday 12:00?

Tags: javascript

```js
const options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric'
};
const dt = new Date('2023-06-16T12:00:00Z').toLocaleDateString('tr-TR', options)
console.log(dt)
```

The code I created is as above.
It just separates date.
How do I format this like 10/03/2013 Friday 12:00

Comment: Look up the documentation for toLocaleDateString and examine the different options you can pass to it.

Comment: Does `Friday, 10/03/2013, 12:00` works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

Here's the code:

```js
const options = {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
      weekday: 'long',
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
    };
    const dt = new Date('2023-06-16T12:00:00Z');
    const formattedDate = `${dt.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
    })}, ${dt.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
      weekday: 'long',
    })}, ${dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
    })}`;
    console.log(formattedDate);
```

---

Since I could only go half trough the answer, here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75410091/18099076) where I've found the whole one.

Firstly, I've added `weekday, hour and minute` inside the `options`, and changed the `locale` to `en-GB` (for desired slashes ( / ) DD/MM format).

So this was the result.

```js
const options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  weekday: 'long',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
};
const dt = new Date('2023-06-16T12:00:00Z').toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options)
console.log(dt)
```

Then, as I mentioned, an user showed me how to format the date even more, like so, and we got the desired output.

```
const formattedDate = `${dt.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
    })}, ${dt.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
      weekday: 'long',
    })}, ${dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: 'numeric',
    })}`;
```