# Is there a way to swap dayweek and date, when formatting a date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date

I've formatted my date like below, but I would like the `weekday` to go after the `DD/MM/YYYY`. Is this possible?

Current output: `Friday, 16/06/2023, 12:00`

Desired output: `16/06/2023, Friday, 12:00`

```js
const options = {
  weekday: 'long',
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',     
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
};
const dt = new Date('2023-06-16T12:00:00Z').toLocaleDateString('en-GB', options)
console.log(dt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by custom code format of required output.

In your case to acheive desired result this code help you.

```js
const options = {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
  weekday: 'long',
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
};
const dt = new Date('2023-06-16T12:00:00Z');
const formattedDate = `${dt.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'numeric',
  day: 'numeric',
})}, ${dt.toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
  weekday: 'long',
})}, ${dt.toLocaleTimeString('en-GB', {
  hour: 'numeric',
  minute: 'numeric',
})}`;
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: If this will help you to find a solution to your question then add it as the right answer for other people to find the right solution in the future.

Comment: I will, don't worry. The rules are that I have to wait for couple of more minutes so I can accept your answer. You'll get your +15 :)